# how to get back root user in fedora?

Tags: fedora, root

Now that CentOS is dead, I might as well move back to fedora, but turns out, I'm really out of the loop with that one.

Apparently, (in f33) your user gets only set up when you reboot into your new install, …and that's it.

No root, just an user. So, I figured I gotta set one up myself and did so, using gnomes graphical tool for it. but `su root` just fails with `Authentication failure` even though I'm 100% certain the password is correct. If I start a new session and log in as root, it works, but turns out I'm now at `/home/roo`, so apparently I just made a new user that had to be shortened to `roo`, since `root` is already taken?

So what weird hoops do I have to jump through, to get a root user to actually do anything with my machine? A quick search for it doesn't yield anything useful. Or is my install broken?

Comment: why do you say *CentOS is dead*?

Comment: Today [IBM's Redhat announced](https://blog.centos.org/2020/12/future-is-centos-stream/) that they are "shifting focus from CentOS Linux, the rebuild of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), to CentOS Stream".  CentOS8 will only be supported until the end of 2021. CentOS7 will be supported until 2024 as planned. After that, no support.

Comment: [RedHat's perspective](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/centos-stream-building-innovative-future-enterprise-linux) is "We’ve informed the CentOS Project Governing Board that we are shifting our investment fully from CentOS Linux to CentOS Stream."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first user in Fedora is in the `wheel` group and can use `sudo` to perform privileged operations ([more about sudo in Fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/performing-administration-tasks-using-sudo/)). `root` account in Fedora exists, it just doesn't have password set by default. All you need to do is set root password using `sudo passwd root` and you should be able to use `su` or `su root` to switch to root account in terminal.

Comment: `sudo` - Huh? Apparently I'm really out of the loop. I'm used to fedora not having that command, so if you quickly wanted to run one thing as root, it was `su -c`. But anyways, that seems like a really convoluted (and undocumented! why doesn't it tell me that I have to do that during install or at first boot?) way, compared to just setting up root during install, especially, since I had to stare at ananconda installing for at least 10 minutes.

Comment: Apparently, it works. Gotta play around with it a bit to see if that really is so.

Comment: `sudo` is installed and configured in Fedora for a while now. When installing from LiveCD user creation and other "installation" steps are "outsourced" to GNOME Initial Setup which runs during first boot and it just creates new user with `sudo`.

Comment: That's a really annoying and useless change and totally doesn't fit the whole trend of making Linux easier and more ready for the mainstream, but oh well… guess the next step will be to abolish any kind of passwords and authentification, because they're complicated and scare and privacy and security are soooo 20th century anyways. But the answer works (for now).